# I want to understand this piece of PHP code (from a Laravel app.php config file)

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, syntax

I'm learning the basics of PHP and Laravel. I need to understand the syntax of this piece of code taken from a Laravel config file named app.php . I shortened the contents of this file to fit here. I'm only interested in the syntax.

```
<?php

return [
    'name' => env('APP_NAME', 'Laravel'),
    'env' => env('APP_ENV', 'production'),
    'providers' => [
        Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
    ],
];
?>
```

I know what return does in a function. It terminates the function and returns a value. But here it is all by itself returning an array I think. Please correct me if I'm wrong. It returns an associative array where the keys are: name, env, providers. The double arrows assign values to the keys in the array. So for instance `env('APP_ENV', 'production');` is assigned as a value to `'env'` key.

Another thing is where this return returns the array? Is this file included in some other file?

The other thing I don't understand is the `env()` call. Is it a built in PHP function? What does it do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where this return returns the array? Is this file included in some other file?

Laravel reads and then uses the arrays returned by config files in the `Illuminate\Config\Repository` class.

So, when you read the value with something like `config('app.name')`, it does:

```
public function get($key, $default = null)
{
    if (is_array($key)) {
        return $this->getMany($key);
    }

    return Arr::get($this->items, $key, $default);
}
```

Where `$this->items` is config data read from config files (the arrays you're talking about). If you curious how and where it Laravel read config files, check the `Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\LoadConfiguration` class:

```
protected function loadConfigurationFiles(Application $app, RepositoryContract $repository)
{
    $files = $this->getConfigurationFiles($app);

    if (! isset($files['app'])) {
        throw new Exception('Unable to load the "app" configuration file.');
    }

    foreach ($files as $key => $path) {
        $repository->set($key, require $path);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`include` can also return a value (in this case an array) that will be assigned to a variable in the script that is doing the include. See the section in the [PHP Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) (immediately below the security warning)

> Also, it's possible to return values from included files. You can take the value of the include call as you would for a normal function.

And look at Example #5

---

And `env()` is a [Laravel function](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-env)

> The env function retrieves the value of an environment variable or returns a default value